# What is "The Rainbow Bridge"?

Tags: death

When my dog passed away, I was told he would meet me by the Rainbow Bridge.  I have heard others mention this anecdote as well.  I understand it has some popularity as an aid in a time of grief due to the loss of a pet.

Can anyone please elaborate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rainbow Bridge is a currently unattributed poem ([Wikipedia mentions multiple contenders for authorship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Bridge_%28pets%29)) sourced from the internet (UseNET) purportedly by way of a canine rescue organization newsletter.  There are multiple interpretations and versions of the poem.  Some versions may mention Heaven directly, I have seen others that do not.  While there are similarities in concept, I do not believe it has any connection to the rainbow bridge of Norse mythology.

It is a coping mechanism and frequents condolence cards given to those who have lost a pet.  I received a card with one version written on it, and a letter from my veterinarian with another iteration of the poem.  There are [many](https://rainbowsbridge.com/poem.htm) [other](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/rec.pets.dogs/KW-Rgq_iOKA) [versions](http://www.scrapbook.com/poems/doc/2907.html) [online](http://www.drsfostersmith.com/pic/article.cfm?aid=1094).  All of them are similar in scope; none seem specific to a species or breed of pet.

Here is a variation of the one I received when my dog passed:

> Just this side of Heaven
>   is a place called Rainbow Bridge.
>   When an animal dies that has been 
>   especially close to someone here, 
>   that pet goes to Rainbow Bridge. 
>   
>   There are meadows and hills 
>   for all of our special friends 
>   so they can run and play together. 
>   There is plenty of food, water and sunshine, 
>   and our friends are warm and comfortable.
>   
>   All the animals who had been ill and old 
>   are restored to health and vigor. 
>   Those who were hurt or maimed 
>   are made whole and strong again, 
>   just as we remember them in our dreams 
>   of days and times gone by. 
>   
>   The animals are happy and content, 
>   except for one small thing; 
>   they each miss someone very special to them, 
>   someone who had to be left behind. 
>   
>   They all run and play together, 
>   but the day comes 
>   when one suddenly stops 
>   and looks into the distance. 
>   His bright eyes are intent; 
>   his eager body begins to quiver. 
>   
>   Suddenly, he breaks from the group, 
>   racing over the green grass, 
>   his legs carrying him faster and faster.
>   
>   You have been spotted, 
>   and when you and your special friend finally meet, 
>   you cling together in joyous reunion, 
>   never to be parted again. 
>   
>   The happy kisses rain upon your face; 
>   your hands again caress the beloved head, 
>   and you look once more 
>   into those trusting eyes, 
>   so long gone from your life 
>   but never absent from your heart.
>   
>   Then you cross the Rainbow Bridge together...